# Why is the profiler not working for me?

Tags: ubuntu, go, windows-10, profiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Given the following toy code, I would expect to be able to run

```
go tool pprof cpu.prof
```

and get useful information about waster1 and waster2, but when I run top in pprof, all I get is:

```
Showing nodes accounting for 0, 0% of 0 total
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
```

It is possible the problem is that I am using WSL to run Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Here is the code I am using:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime/pprof"
)

func waster2() int {
    j := 0;
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        j += waster1()
    }
    return j
}

func waster1() int {
    j := 0;
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        j++
    }
    return j
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("cpu.prof")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not create CPU profile: ", err)
    }

    if err := pprof.StartCPUProfile(f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not start CPU profile: ", err)
    }

    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()

    j := waster2()

    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

Comment: Looks like it does the same thing on Debian running by itself, so the Windows 10 thing is a red herring.

Comment: First you need to provide the binary as an argument to `pprof`. How long does your program run? You may not have enough samples to make a meaningful profile.

Comment: @JimB add sleeps to the functions (over 10 second runtime now) and the binary to the tool command, still no output.

Comment: It’s possible that SIGPROF just doesn’t work in WSL, I’m not sure how one would go about tracing that on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Running on windows also produces no samples in the profiler. The following [article](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) from the go blog states the following:

```
When CPU profiling is enabled, the Go program stops about 100 times per second and 
records a sample consisting of the program counters on the currently executing 
goroutine's stack.
```

When running your code takes less that 2ms, so does not allow the profiler to take samples. Increase your loop count from 100 to 10000 and then you should see some samples in your output.

On another note, remember to close your file `f`. Like so:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("could not create CPU profile: ", err)
}
defer f.Close()
```

Comment: I added sleeps to the functions and the defer. It ran for over 10 seconds and still no output in pprof.

Comment: The profiler does not track time the CPU is not working. Have you tried increasing the max loop count?